# Need regex pattern for parsing out elements of string that are similar

Tags: python, regex, text

For example, the string I'm trying to parse is:

**#12 Alabama St. (AL) (12-14)**

What would be the regex to select "Alabama St. (AL)"? I am able to get the (12-14) using:

```
\(([0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2})\)
```

Comment: Please let know if my answer below works for you, or if you need more adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
#\d+\s*(.*?)\s*\(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbiKxQ/1).

**Details**

- `#\d+` - `#` and then 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\)` - `(`, 1 or 2 digits, `-`, 1 or 2 digits, `)`.

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##ZY2xCsIwFAD3fMWjHfpebQOpTkKV7m6uWaKNtmCa8BpBEb89VnBzuuW4C884@Gmd0uiC5whsRbSPCC1kuWqgu5mTcQaOUQJ2BwJUTa02lAm3KGzlbA2fB@Qi1/1KzyXKck8LNer@parmXf@oqajgmyYxXsBtBUDgcYro5JX9PaAighza3d8zpQ8):

```
import re
text = "#12 Alabama St. (AL) (12-14)"
m = re.search(r'#\d+\s*(.*?)\s*\(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}\)', text)
if m:
  print(m.group(1)) # => Alabama St. (AL)
```